# Vuex state with same name gets nulled

Tags: vuex

I have a Vuex module with state like this:

```
const state = {
  items: [],
  selectedItem: {
    id: null,
    name: "",
  }
}
```

And in my I let the user add the `selectedItem` to the `items`-array.

However, when I set the `selectedItem` I want to clear the old one, so I run a mutation that basically sets `id` and `name` to null. But this seems to clear the `id` and `name` of the `selectedItem` in the `items` array also!

My clearing mutation looks like this:

```
  clearSelectedItem: function(state) {
    state.items.selectedItem.id = null;
    state.items.selectedItem.name = "";
  },
```

To my understanding this should only clear the `selectedItem` outside of the `items` array, but it clears absolutely everything. Is there any syntax I can use to just get the single `selectedItem`?

Answer (score 0):

> I let the user add the selectedItem to the items-array.

It sounds to me like you are adding the object to the array by reference. Have you tried cloning the values into a new object and then adding the new object to the items-array instead?

Or you could try setting your clearing function to:

```
clearSelectedItem: function(state) {
  state.items.selectedItem = {
    id:null,
    name:""
  };
},
```